# Database connection failed on restart of sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

We are getting the below error when restarting the sonarqube 6.7.2, can someone please advise. Thank you.

```
2018.04.04 10:31:44 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] #1619 'Restore 'sonar-users' group': failure | time=8ms
2018.04.04 10:31:44 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] Executed DB migrations: failure | time=9ms
2018.04.04 10:31:44 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] DB migration failed | time=56ms
2018.04.04 10:31:44 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] DB migration ended with an exception
org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepExecutionException: Execution of migration step #1619 'Restore 'sonar-users' group' failed
        at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:79)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:67)
```

Comment: To be clear, this is after a migration from a previous version, right? It would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to include that previous version #.

Comment: it would be helpful to have more logs too.

Comment: we took the production(sonarqube is 5.6.3) RDS snapshot and updated the jdbc url in stage sonarqube(6.7.2) sonar.properties and restarted the sonarqube.service

Comment: Related issue and fix here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/HlFFqOPVZ5E

Comment: My sonarqube is not up and I am unable to  create a new group with the default name using sonarqube UI. As per above link it is resolved by creating the default group, can someone please let me know how to create the default group(sonarqube 6.7.2 UI is not up).Thanks.

Comment: Can someone please let me know where to create a new group with the default name as per the link  groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/HlFFqOPVZ5E – Simon Brandhof - SonarSource